# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE || Can't create new vue app with vue/cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I'm trying to create a new vue app by vue cli. Here is my environment info:

```
OS: Windows 11
Node version: 14.16.1
npm version: 6.14.12
vue cli version: 4.5.13
```

However, when I try to create an app by hitting `vue create myapp`, it throws following error

[image]

I've [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42308879/10652537), but it's not working.

Comment: before running "vue create myapp" try to run "node -v" and confirm node version

Comment: it's `14.16.1`. I've mentioned above

Comment: You may need to add `node.exe` to your PATH environment variable.