# Npm React js start error - ELIFECYCLE ERRNO1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
The system cannot find the path specified.

    npm ERR! 
    code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! react-able-pro@1.0.0 start: `react-scripts start`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the react-able-pro@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

ive got some error when i npm start, it always like this when i restart my pc,
ive already use

1. npm cache clear --force
2. deleting my modules app and package-lock.jason
3. npm install

and its doesnt work at all, can you guys help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: The error is saying that `react-scripts` is an unknown command. If it's declared properly as a (dev) dependency, try `npx react-scripts start` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library that you are trying to run is "react-able-pro". Through a search on [www.npmjs.com](http://www.npmjs.com) for this library, I was not able to find it. However I was able to find [react-table-pro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-pro).

It looks like a typo. try to fix your package.json file dependencies/devDependencies and then try to reinstall