# CircleCI AWS: Angular build fails with ELIFECYCLE

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, build, circleci

I have an AWS S3 bucket to host an angular app.
The S3 bucket works fine with AWS CLI. But the build app job in CircleCI fails!

NOTE: **I can build the app locally and then deploy it to the s3 bucket successfully**.

S3 has public access, the bucket policy for public read access, and has been enabled to host an `index.html`.

**Failed job** in CircleCI to build the angular app:

[image: build job cicleci]

**CircleCI configuration file** (`config.yml`):

[image: config.yml]

The `npm run frontend:build` command runs `ng build` to create the `www` folder and then deploys the app.

This is what I got at the end of the big output file in CircleCI:

[image: log file]

Answer (score 1):

Your CircleCI instance seems to be out of:

- RAM
- Or even Storage

Simply increase both temporarily, by 1 or 2 GB each, to see if that fixes the issue.

---

Normally there should be no caching in CI, but if your's has, also try to clear cache with commands mentioned at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505612/8740349

Also, above link suggests re-creating `package-lock.json`, but as your local works, ensure CI uses same `package-lock.json` file (maybe by tracking it in Git).

Comment: so you mean I should add new run ```npm cache clean --force``` before run of ```npm run frontend:install``` in the circleci config.yml ?

Comment: @someone Before `npm install`, also, that's just one of the link's commands. Try all, is CI, your files don't get really deleted.

Comment: @someone consider accepting if this was helpful (there should be tick-mark button somewhere above).

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that I put **package-lock.json** in **.gitignore** so I remove it then I add `npm cache clean --force` before `npm install` of the frontend and it works fine. Thanks a lot for @Top-Master

Comment: The question has no way for us to answer like above, but see my edit.