# Installing npm package sqlite3 on rasberrypi 4 is resulting in a ELIFECYCLE error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to install the sqlite3 npm package on my raspberry pi 4 (not sure if that is relevant) so I can connect my sqlite database to a node.js application I'm building but every time I try to do so I get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.1.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.1.6 install script.
```

I've tried following the steps found in StackOverflow question [How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle) like clearing the cache, deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json files however I am still getting the same errors

I've googled around for some other solutions to try but none of those have worked as well