# Issue with adding EFS file system policy through CDK V1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-efs

We have a CDK based code repo to generate AWS resources. We have an AWS `Lambda` for which the `EFS` was created, the code is written in **CDK v1** (using `aws-cdk/aws-efs` ).

To that I want to [add file system policy to Elastic File System (EFS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/efs-encrypted-file-systems/encryption-of-data-in-transit.html) to enforce encryption in transit. The change itself is clear.

In **CDK V2** (using `aws-cdk-lib`) this change would be simple as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_efs-readme.html).

```js
import * as efs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-efs"
....
    const fileSystemPolicy = new iam.PolicyDocument({
      statements: [new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        actions: [
          "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
          "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
          "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"
        ],
        conditions: {
          Bool: { "aws:SecureTransport": "true" }
        }
      })]
    })

    const cfFs = new efs.FileSystem(this, 'MyLambdaFilesystem', {
      vpc: vpc,
      fileSystemPolicy: fileSystemPolicy
    });
```

However, I could not find a way to do it with **CDK v1** which is what I need. Looked at [this doc for lambda.FileSystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.FileSystem.html) which mentions `FileSystemConfig` containing `policies` but seems like we cannot set that.

---

**Note:**

Deleted the *Updates* from the question here to avoid causing confusion, as the updated answer resolves this issue.

Comment: @fedonev Added the minimal policy that works with edits to the generated ones, pls take a look. thanks

Comment: Aha, try `fileSystemPolicy.toJSON()` in the property override.  My override command synthesizes fine (using V2) without the added `toJSON()` method, but perhaps V1 needs it.

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely, that generated the correct policy. However my tests are failing `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
` even though I updated them to match, that too it shows no diff there `    - Snapshot  - 0
    + Received  + 0
`
I tried this but does not help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505612/948268. 
checking further

Comment: It was just an issue due to formatting, fixed by running `npm test -- -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release [2.72.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v2.72.0) added the `fileSystemPolicy` prop to the EFS `FileSystem` construct in March 2023.

For CDK v1, set the `FileSystemPolicy` manually with an [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) property override:

```js
const cfFs = new efs.FileSystem(this, "MyLambdaFilesystem", {
  vpc: vpc
});

const cfnCfFs = cfFs.node.defaultChild as efs.CfnFileSystem;
cfnCfFs.addPropertyOverride("FileSystemPolicy", fileSystemPolicy.toJSON());
```

The above code produces the same synthesized CloudFormation output as OP's v2 code.

---

[Edit]:  Here is the `FileSystemPolicy` from the CloudFormation template that `cdk synth` creates for me:

```js
"MyLambdaFilesSystemEAD92DBE": {
 "Type": "AWS::EFS::FileSystem",
 "Properties": {
  "Encrypted": true,
  "FileSystemPolicy": {
   "Statement": [
    {
     "Action": [
      "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
      "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
      "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"
     ],
     "Condition": {
      "Bool": {
       "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
      }
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
     }
    }
   ],
   "Version": "2012-10-17"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, This is nice, will try it.

Comment: I am getting an error when applying the policy generated by this code. Updated that in my question under UPDATE#2.