# Deleting directories in command prompt

Tags: command-prompt

I accidentally made a directory that had a .py ending and so I want to delete this directory in command prompt. I do not know how can someone give me the command I should use for this? I basically want to delete the actual directory. I am on windows 10 and the directory is empty.

Comment: what operating system? rm -rf for mac, rmdir or rd for dos. Is it empty?

Comment: yeah, its an empty directory and I'm on windows 10.

Comment: rd *.py (or actually fill in the name) should do it.

Comment: If you need fancier see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97875/rm-rf-equivalent-for-windows

Comment: Thanks Jeremy rd *.py worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the directory was empty and it was a Windows system `rd *.py` worked. For more complicated cases [more general answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97875/rm-rf-equivalent-for-windows) has lots.